# Problems in project_create.sh while running bash file

Tags: android, opencv, android-ndk

I'm following tutorial on http://www.stanford.edu/class/ee368/Android/Tutorial-2-OpenCV-for-Android-Setup-Linux.pdf

But when it comes to: 
`sh  ./project_create.sh` in the android-jni folder, I get this error :

```
Error: The project either has no target set or the target is invalid.
Please provide a --target to the 'android update' command.
```

The contents of the project_create.sh file are

```
#!/bin/sh
#this generates an ant based cli build of the android-jni project

android update project --name android-opencv \
--path .
```

Answer (score 1):

Add `--target=android-8` (or any other reported by the `android list target -c` command) to the command line. `android-8` is the minimal required by OpenCV.

Also, the tutorial is deprecated and android-opencv example were removed from OpenCV before the 2.3.1 release.

Comment: i tried giving target as android-8,but now it says:  android: command not found.It is most erratic that it has started giving this error now.Even simply typing android at command line gives this error.The android-sdk is properly installed .

Comment: Just tried (2014), `--target=android-19` did not work but `--target android-19` worked. I guess the syntax changes from equals to space.

Answer (score 0):

Please open your terminal, then go to home (`cd ~`), then type `gedit .profile`
then add following lines at the end of file.

```
 export NDK=/home/JohnDoe/android-ndk-r4-crystax
 export SDK=/home/JohnDoe/android-sdk-linux
 export ANT_HOME=/home/JohnDoe/apache-ant-1.8.3
 export JAVA_HOME=/home/JohnDoe/jdk1.7.0_03
 export OPCV=/home/JohnDoe/opencv
 export PATH=$NDK:$SDK/tools:$SDK/platform-tools:$ANT_HOME/bin:$JAVA_HOME/bin:$PATH
```

(**Please don't forget to change NDK, SDK etc paths accordingl to your setup**).

I faced the same problem while using the Stanford tutorial, and solved it using above way.

Regards